# KivyMD 'MDMenuItem' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to click MDMenuItem to get text or do something.
But an error say "AttributeError: 'MDMenuItem' object has no attribute 'text'     "

.py file like this

```
class MDMenuItem(Widget):
    pass

class MyScreen(Screen):
    menu_items = [
    {'viewclass': 'MDMenuItem',
     'text': 'text1'},
    {'viewclass': 'MDMenuItem',
     'text': 'text2'},
    ]

    def change_variable(self, value):
        print("\nvalue=", value)
        self.VARIABLE = value
        print("\tself.VARIABLE=", self.VARIABLE)
```

.kv file like this:

```
#:import MDDropdownMenu kivymd.menu.MDDropdownMenu
#:import MDRaisedButton kivymd.button.MDRaisedButton
<MDMenuItem>:
    on_release: root.change_variable(self.text)

<MyScreen>:
    name: myscrn
    MDRaisedButton:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 3 * dp(48), dp(48)
        text: 'MDButton'
        opposite_colors: True
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        on_release: MDDropdownMenu(items=root.menu_items, width_mult=4).open(self)
```

What should I do?

**Edit:**
Thank you for your reply. In my case, this .py subprogram not content 'App'. I don't want to put the method into main.py because I want main.py to stay clean.(Just content import, builder.load_file, add_wiget...)

So I want to call method without use 'app.something'.
Can I use root.something or other methods to call change_variable and get text?

Answer (score 0):

## *Note:*

*The following solution is using [KivyMD version 0.1.2](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD).*

## AttributeError

> AttributeError: 'MDMenuItem' object has no attribute 'text'

The error was due wrong definition for class MDMenuItem. It was defined with an inheritance of a Widget which does not has the attribute, 'text'.

## Actual Definition of MDMenuItem

```
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class MDMenuItem(RecycleDataViewBehavior, ButtonBehavior, BoxLayout):
    text = StringProperty()
```

## Solution

There is no need to define class MDMenuItem in main.py. Remove it and the program will run.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen


class MyScreen(Screen):
    VARIABLE = ""

    menu_items = [
    {'viewclass': 'MDMenuItem',
     'text': 'text1'},
    {'viewclass': 'MDMenuItem',
     'text': 'text2'},
    ]

    def change_variable(self, value):
        print("\nvalue=", value)
        self.VARIABLE = value
        print("\tself.VARIABLE=", self.VARIABLE)


class MainApp(App):
    title = "KivyMD MDDropdownMenu Demo"
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        return MyScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:import MDDropdownMenu kivymd.menu.MDDropdownMenu
#:import MDRaisedButton kivymd.button.MDRaisedButton

<MDMenuItem>:
    on_release: app.root.change_variable(self.text)

<MyScreen>:
    name: 'myscrn'
    MDRaisedButton:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 3 * dp(48), dp(48)
        text: 'MDButton'
        opposite_colors: True
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        on_release: MDDropdownMenu(items=root.menu_items, width_mult=4).open(self)
```

## Output

[image: KivyMD MDDropdownMenu]

Answer (score 0):

I removed class MDMenuItem and change "root.change_variable" to "app.root.get_screen('MyScreen').change_variable". It's work!!!
The "app.root" treated as "screen.manager" in this case. I don't know why but it just work.

.py

```
class MyScreen(Screen):

    menu_items = [
        {'viewclass': 'MDMenuItem',
        'text': 'text1'},
        {'viewclass': 'MDMenuItem',
        'text': 'text2'},
    ]

    def change_variable(self, value):
        print("\nvalue=", value)
        self.VARIABLE = value
        print("\tself.VARIABLE=", self.VARIABLE)
```

.kv

```
#:import MDDropdownMenu kivymd.menu.MDDropdownMenu
#:import MDRaisedButton kivymd.button.MDRaisedButton
<MDMenuItem>:
    on_release: app.root.get_screen("MyScreen").change_variable(self.text)
```